# Can I share HttpRuntime.Cache between applications?

Tags: asp.net, httpruntime.cache

I have a website setup like this:

> /Web --this is the client facing
>   site
>  /Web/Admin --this is the
>   backend system and is setup as a
>   Virtual Application

I'm using HttpRuntime.Cache for caching calls to the database. What I want to be able to do is clear something that is cached on the /Web site from the /Web/Admin site. It appears though that HttpRuntime.Cache is a single instance per application. Anyway around this without using a distributed caching system.

Comment: why cant you use a distributed cache like Memcached?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with an http handler on the main site. Call the handler from your admin site with some parameter(s) to tell it what to remove from cache, then the handler cann access the cache and remove the item.

Comment: Setting this up as a service might be a little cleaner, and provide better mechanisms for security and authentication.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be [Windows AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139632.aspx).

Comment: Problem is that I need a non-distributed caching system. It's a hosted environment, so installing a distributed cache is not an option.